# How to: UDF function to extract substring?

Tags: sql-server, string, user-defined-functions

How to extract substring from input string like this

```
'{\lang1252 All rights reserved}'
```

i.e. in common case it is

1)    {\lettersdigits \lettersdigits \lettersdigits any plain text} 
2)     {\lettersdigits The text \lettersdigits the part2 \lettersdigits any plain text}

The expected results are:
1) any plain text
2) The text the part2 any plain text

The command starts \, then letters, then optional digits.
Also, if command not started from \ it is text and should be extracted as a text.

Comment: Is the expected result always going to be "All rights reserved"?

Comment: In my example - yes, I edit the 1st post

Comment: There is not a built-in function(s) to do this in MS SQL AFAIK. However, MS SQL supports CLR, thus you could write a UDF say in C# to do this with RegEx. If your data is not large, then getting the data to local first and then filtering by regex is an easier task (for example Linq To SQL AsEnumerable() then RegEx).

Comment: Yes, you are right. The data is not so large, also I have my SQLCLR function but I need to have T-SQL (noSQLCLR) function because of Azure etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reverse` the string, find the index of first occurance of '\' using `charindex` and use `substring` to find the desired output.

Try like following.

```
declare @var varchar(100)='{\lettersdigits \letters123 \lettersdigit45 any plain text}'
select substring(col,patindex('% %', col), len(col)- patindex('% %', col))
from
 (
   select  reverse(substring(reverse(@var),2,charindex('\',reverse(@var))-2)) col
  ) t
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ORW94056)</kbd>**

**Edit** (Based on the question update):

You can create a scaler valued function of below code and it will work for you.

```
declare @xml  xml
declare @str as varchar(100)
declare @output varchar(max)
--SET @str='{\lettersdigits \lettersdigits \lettersdigits any plain text}'
SET @str='{\lettersdigits The text \lettersdigits the part2 \lettersdigits any plain text}'
select @xml =  cast(('<X>'+replace(@str,'\' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml) 
select @output= output from
(
    select stuff(
    (
        select substring(col,patindex('% %', col), len(col)- patindex('% %', col)+1) from
        (
            select replace(replace(value,'}',''),'{','') col from
            (
               SELECT LTRIM(N.value('.', 'varchar(100)')) as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
            ) t1
        ) t2
    for xml path('')),1,1,'') as [output]
) t
select @output
```

**<kbd>[DEMO 2](http://rextester.com/MOU66133)</kbd>**

Comment: There is important this format: a command started \, then set of letters then optional digits \lettersdigits

Comment: @Oleg, I am not getting what you are asking for, can you explain it in more details. If you check the demo, you will get the desired output.

Comment: @Oleg, I have updated the answer and demo, now it will work as expected.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works, But this case does not: declare @var varchar(100)='{\lettersdigits MY TEXT1 \letters123 MY TEXT2 \lettersdigit45 MY TEXT3}'

Comment: It works. As a first solution works, will test and improve. Thanx!

Comment: Glad it worked, definitely it needs lot of improvement, i just wrote without checking much.